# Freeform Pro – calculate total

Tags: solspace-freeform

Hi think this is a long shot! but just incase…
would it be possible to calculate a total with Freeform pro, eg for an order form featuring:

**Number of items?**

if there were 10 selected (drop down) at £20 *each* the result then calculated and entered as a field (automatically) would thus be £200?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your form markup here? You could do this with a little js or jquery. This fiddle should give you a good starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/8mnQR/1/